# Binary search function which accepts array with different types

Tags: c, function, binary-search

I want to write a binary search function which will take pointer to an array as input and find the index of the searchable element.

```
uint8_t binary_search(uint8_t * array, uint8_t element);
```

but the arrays I want to pass to this function have different types(unsigned 8 bit, unsigned 16 bit, signed 8 bit etc)

I was thinking of an approach where I can pass the array as a void pointer and then typecast it based on size, but I am unable to find a proper way to implement it.

```
uint8_t binary_search(void * array, uint8_t element)
{
  if(sizeof(array[0] == 1)
  {
  }
  else if
  .
  .
  .
}
```

The last option is to pass multiple arrays to a function and select based on size again, but I was hoping if there was a better way to deal with situation like this.

any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The library function [bsearch](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bsearch.3.html) solves this by having member size and comparison function as arguments. You can search anything you like using this model (as long as it is in a sorted array). If you have a predefined set of types, you could have an extra `enum` argument specifying which type the caller wants.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [bsearch](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bsearch.3.html) function from standard library, or write something similar.

Here, an example of comparing function.

```
int cmp_i8(const void *first, const void *second)
{
    const int8_t *fst = first;
    const int8_t *snd = second;
    if (*fst < *snd) return -1;
    else if (*fst == *snd) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

Comment: A couple of minor style points.  In a case like this where the type is a simple value, I'd use `int8_t fst = *(const int8_t *)first;` to avoid the dereferencing in the comparisons.  As a general rule, it is best to test for “less than” then “greater than” (or vice versa) and assume “equal to” last.  This is most valuable when dealing with a multi-part comparison on a structure type (where you would use pointers).  You test on the first field, and if they are equal, you do the “less than” and “greater than” on the second field, and so on, leaving “equal to” as the last option.

Comment: `else` is superfluous after a block containing `return;` Don't clutter code...